# isomorphic : how can I have a form already filled (from the database)

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I have a form already filled (from the database) in a modification of an object.
here is my code:

```
this.FP_fiche2 = isc.DynamicForm.create({

ID: this.ID+"_fiche2"
,autoDraw:false
,canRemoveRecords: true
,FP_Parent:this.ID
,dataSource: crm_objects
,width: 250
,height: 350
,canReorderRecords: true
,selectionType :"single"    
,canEdit: true
,editEvent: "doubleClick"
,autoSaveEdits:true

,fields: [ 
,{name:"crm_obj_name", title:"Name" ,width:"120",align:"",canEdit:true,showHover:true, displayField:"crm_obj_name"}
,{name:"crm_obj_desc", title:"Description" ,width:"120",align:"left",canEdit:true,showHover:t rue}
,{name: "crm_obj_background", title: "Background",type: "color", width:"120",align:"left",canEdit:true,showHover:tr ue}
,{name: "crm_obj_forecolor", title: "Color", type: "color",width:"120",align:"left",canEdit:true,show Hover:true}
,{name:"crm_obj_isactive", title:"IsActive",width:"120" ,align:"left",canEdit:true,showHover:true}
]
});
```

Comment: Thats quite less info about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to modify an object so I show this form and I want it to be filled with the values ​​of this object with the possibility of modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is solved! 
I had to do this for each field:

```
 value: record.field.name
```